# Why would this code lead to infinite loop/recursive

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
var original_selectCallback = window.selectCallback;
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
  original_selectCallback(variant, selector);
  console.log(variant + " " + selector);
};
```

Somehow, the 2nd line:

```
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector)
```

leads to a recursive call to selectCallback.  My understanding is that I am redefining the selectCallback function.  So why would this be a recursive call?
Any suggestions/advice is appreciated.

Comment: i cant see what your question?

Comment: The code should work for the first time but will fail after page refresh. have you refreshed the page?

Comment: It's not recursive, unless `selectCallback` was originally calling upon itself already and was expecting a return value or something to stop the recursion.

Comment: Can you include the original definition of `window.selectCallback`?

Comment: Did you forget your question?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with the code you've posted:

```js
var selectCallback = function() { console.log('original'); };
var original_selectCallback = selectCallback;
var selectCallback = function() {
 original_selectCallback();
 console.log('wrapper');
};
selectCallback();
```

The error is likely in the initial definition of `window.selectCallback`, which is not shown here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no recursion here and that is quite easy to demonstrate:

```js
let someFn = function () { console.log('original'); };
let originalSomeFn = someFn;

someFn = function () {
  originalSomeFn();
  console.log('decorated');
};

someFn();
```

However, the original function may be involved in a recursive algorithm somewhere and your wrapper function might not entirely fulfill the proper behavioral contract of the original function.

To make sure here's how you should be wrapping the original function. I also opted for a closure to avoid a global `originalSomeFn` variable.

```js
let someFn = function () {
    console.log('original');
    return 1;
};

someFn = (function (originalSomeFn) {
  return function () {
    let result = originalSomeFn.apply(this, arguments);

    console.log('decorated');

    return result;
  };
})(someFn);

console.log(someFn());
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's check your code:

```
var original_selectCallback = window.selectCallback;
```

creates new variable that refers to function `selectCallback`.

---

```
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
```

creates `window.selectCallback` function (because it's in `window` scope).

---

Now inner part of function

```
original_selectCallback(variant, selector);
```

will call `window.original_selectCallback` that is same as `window.selectCallback` that is same function where you are now.

So you make recursion with `selectCallback` that never ends.